# Seam 2 with conversation and Internet Explorer doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, seam, seam-conversation

I have a strange problem in my application with Seam (2.1) and Internet explorer.

With Firefox, all work fine.
I have a bean in conversation scope which is used in my page.
When I go on my page, this bean is created, and when I made an action on my page (submit a form for example), the bean already exists and all these data are present.

But in Internet explorer (7 and 8), the bean is created at each call of the page. So I lost every data in this bean.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do they have cookies allowed?

Comment: Please, post some code, at least the <h:form> element and the button which raises the action.

Comment: By editing my post to post the code, I have found the problem. I post an answer to explain it if someone else has the problem. Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and the solution:

I had a h:form AND a a4j:form mixed like this (in summary):

```
<h:form>
<a4j:form>
</a4j:form>
</h:form>
```

So the generated html contains two form imbricated. On firefox, no problem but IE doesn't like it.

I delete the a4j:form and all work fine.